# Django max_length for IntegerField

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have this model field:

```
id_student = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True, max_length=10)
```

The `max_length` restriction doesn't work. I can log in to the admin and create a student with an id with more than 10 chars. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Django ignores `max_length` for integer fields, and will warn you in Django 1.8+. See [ticket 23801](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23801) for more details.

You can either use a max value validator,

```
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    id_student = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True, validators=[MaxValueValidator(9999999999)])
```

or use a `CharField` to store the id, and use a regex validator to ensure that the id is entirely made of digits. This would have the advantage of allowing ids that start with zero.

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    id_student = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=10, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')])
```