# how to keep fixed_length of Integerfield in django models

Tags: python, django, models

I have one integer field to store Pincodes. I want to set length of integer field to be only 6  how can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30849862/django-max-length-for-integerfield

Answer (score 3):

hi you can use MinLengthValidator. Hope this code helps to you

```
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator

class YourModel(models.Model):
   pincode = models.IntegerField('Pincode', max_length=6, 
                              validators=[MinLengthValidator(6)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Django has a concept of validators. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/validators/)
Your problem can be solved by adding this piece of code :

```
 pincodes = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(6),MinLengthValidator(6)])
```

Comment: `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`

Answer (score 0):

Django has the validators that can be used in models. Hope this helps..

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    even_field = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_even])

from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

def validate_even(value):
    if value % 2 != 0:
        raise ValidationError(
            _('%(value)s is not an even number'),
            params={'value': value},
        )
```