# FAILED (errors=4) Destroying test database for alias 'default'

Tags: python, django

I got an error,

```
FAILED (errors=4)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I wrote in tests.py

```
#coding:utf-8
from django.test import TestCase
from app.models import User

# Create your tests here.
class UserModelTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user1 = User.objects.create(name='Tom', group = 'A',age=20,rank=1)

    def test_user1_name(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.user1.name, 'Tom')

    def test_user1_group(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.user1.group, 'A')

    def test_user1_age(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.user1.age, 20)

    def test_user1_rank(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.user1.rank, 1)
```

Traceback shows
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

models.py is

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    group = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(max_length=10,null=True)
    rank = models.IntegerField(max_length=10,null=True)
```

I cannot understand why int error happens because I use int type in age.
How can I fix this?What should I write?

```
Full traceback is
File "/Users/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 393, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/Users/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 806, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Users/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 836, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/Users/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 922, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/Users/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 961, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/Users/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1060, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/Users/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1098, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "/Users/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1051, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/Users/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1051, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/Users/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1050, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "/Users/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 990, in prepare_value
    value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
  File "/Users/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 766, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/Users/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 758, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/Users/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1849, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 25 tests in 0.143s

FAILED (errors=25)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
(myenv) CA2641:app uu121291$
```

Comment: Can you show me your user models here?

Comment: In your last test function you used a `self.assertEqual(self.user1.age, 1)` may be this could be a  `self.assertEqual(self.user1.rank, 1)`

Comment: @NIKHILRANE I updated my question.if u know something please help me.And u r right,self.user1.rank, 1 is right.I edited it.

Comment: Could you show the full traceback too?

Comment: There might be an issue with Django warning you about the IntegerFields having a max_length specified. Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30849862/django-max-length-for-integerfield

Comment: @WillKeeling I updated full traceback in my question

Comment: what's the value of `value` variable?

Comment: As with your last question, "Destroying test database..." is **not** the error; that's just what the test runner does to clean up.